# How i can convert the following SQL Query to Doctrine

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can I convert the following SQL Query to Doctrine?

```
select * from `Leave_types` 
where (leave_name = in_leave_name or leave_code=in_leave_code) 
and academic_year_id =in_academic_year_id
```

I trying the follow code:

```
    $em = $this->doctrine->em;
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('lt');
    $qb->from('Entity\LeaveTypes', 'lt');
    $qb->innerjoin('lt.academicYear', 'ay');
    $qb->where('ay.academicId = :academicId');
    $qb->andwhere(
        $qb->orWhere('leaveName', '?1'),
        $qb->orWhere('leaveCode', '?2')
    );
    $qb->setParameter('academicId', $add_data['academic_year_id']);
    $qb->setParameter(1, $add_data['leave_name']);
    $qb->setParameter(2, $add_data['leave_code']);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: `in_leave_name`,`in_leave_code` and `in_academic_year_id`. What are they?

Comment: these are parameter send in producer

Comment: So what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: how i can write the true condition in doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone, 
I solve the issue using

```
 $qb->where('ay.academicId = :academicId');
 $qb->andWhere('lt.leaveName = :leaveName OR lt.leaveCode = :leaveCode');
```